# Applet isn't painting unless I resize

Tags: java, applet, paint

Hmm, its obviously a paint issue. I've tried painting my panel which contains my applet, and painting my applet. None of them have worked. Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: can you show some skeleton code of your paint method? Or your UI construction method?

Comment: I didn't create a paint() method. My UI looks like this: http://pastebin.com/yBvbb5Xt

and then AppletLoader:
http://pastebin.com/DGkGvhdj

I only included the stuff you need to see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem, which was solved by moving the

```
this.setVisible(true);
```

command to after ALL the code that sets up the GUI had been finished, rather than having it at the start or somewhere in the middle.

In your case I would suggest moving it to before (or maybe after, depending on your code) the line

```
app.startClient();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I only included the stuff you need to see

How do you know what we need to see? By definition you have a problem and until the problem is solved you don't know what code is or isn't relevant which is why you should be posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

For example are you extending JApplet? Where is your code for the init() method?

But before reposting a proper SSCCE, why don't you start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on "[How to Make Applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html)", for a working example of an applet.